# Facebook ads api add ad error

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am using Facebook ads api for create campaigns, adsets and ads. I can create campaigns and adsets successfully. Also I could create ads until update the api.

When I was try to add new ad it gives me an error like this:

"`Error: com.facebook.ads.sdk.APIException$FailedRequestException: {"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":1885833,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Ad Must Be Associated With a Facebook Page","error_user_msg":"Ads and ad creatives must be associated with a Facebook Page. Try connecting your ad or ad creative to a Page and resubmit your ad.","fbtrace_id":"Edck5KvGF05"}`"

Example create new Ad Creative code is below:

```
AdAccount account = new AdAccount(accountID, context);
AdCreative creative = account.createAdCreative()
                        .setTitle("Java SDK Test Creative")
                        .setBody("Java SDK Test Creative")
                        .setImageUrl(adURL) // From URL
                        .setLinkUrl("www.facebook.com")
                        .setObjectUrl("www.facebook.com")
                        .execute();
```

All parameters are true. I could not solve the problem.Can someone please help me? 
Thanks